# Nearby Notifications not appearing in Android

Tags: google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

## Nearby Notifications from beacons not appearing anymore!

**Previous Successful Beacon Config.** -
I have previously configured several different vendor beacons as EddystoneUID, iBeacon, and UriBeacon.  I registered the beacons through "Beacon Tools" and further configured through Google Beacon > Dashboard.

**Previous Success with Notifications** -
I enabled "Nearby / Physical Web" in chrome, and everything was working okay. The notifications where popping up in the Notification Tray as desired (maybe not as great as wanted).

**Process no longer working**-
I revisited this process with more beacons, (HTTPS) is available for each URL associated with the beacon.  The notifications are no longer working **Physical Web App no longer sees the Notifications / Beacons** all setting have been checked. **"** The only way to see the beacons / Notifications now **"** is (Android) -> Settings -> Personalize -> Google -> Services -> Nearby **Voila** I can see Notifications to the desired URL's.  I have tried reconfiguration/reboot etc, and can't get the notifications to re-appear at all.

I have searched for an answer and there doesn't seem to be any other complaints that match this issue well, there are people not enabling Nearby, this is definitely not the issue I have.

The closest if have found is *https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview* but I would suspect much more traffic on this issue if it were so.

Am I missing something in settings that would do this?

My phone is Galaxy Note 4

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you missed anything in your settings. I think your problem is related to the current bug in android which is the reason for the temporarily muting. You can have a look at the discussion about this bug on GitHub (https://github.com/google/eddystone/issues/190) to make sure your settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2016, **Nearby notifications are currently disabled on Google's servers, and won't be re-enabled until sometime in December 2016** when a new Google Play Services is rolled out to users.

You can follow the [same thread](https://github.com/google/eddystone/issues/190) that @rené mentioned for updates.